# Which CSS Code shall help to open an element after a specific element?

Tags: css

```
body {
        font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size: 13px;
        color:#333
}

p {
        padding: 10px;
}

#wrapper {
        width: 100%;
        min-width: 340px;
        max-width: 1000px;
        margin: 0 auto;
}

#header {
        float: left;
        height: 100px;
        width: 100%;
        background: #FFFFFF;
}

#title 
{
        float: left;
        height: 40px;
        width: 100%;
        background: #ffffff;
}
#description 
{
        float: left;
        height: 40px;
        width: 100%;
        background: #f2f2f2;
}

#navigation {
        float: left;
        height: 50px;
        width: 100%;
        background: #FFFFFF;
}

#contentliquid {
        float: left;
        width: 100%;
}

#content {
        background: #FFFFFF;
        margin-right: 340px;
}
#leftcolumn 
{
        background: #FFFFFF;
        width: 200px;
        float: left;
        margin-left: -100%;
}
#rightcolumn {
        background: #FFFFFF;
        width: 340px;
        margin-left: -340px;
        float: left;
}

#footer {
        height: 50px;
        width: 100%;
        background: #FFFFFF;
        clear: both;
}
```

This is the CSS i generated. Assuming that this is a liquid layout style of a website, I need to open the RIGHT COLUMN properties after the CONTENT COLUMN (except desktop browsers.)

That is, when this page loads in Desktop Browsers the right column will be in right side. But when this page load in mobile, tablet pc, that right column should go below the Content Area. (Like responsive themes)

Can anyone help me in this regard?

Comment: What do you mean by "open"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is media queries, which will apply css only when certain conditions are met. See more details [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/):

So for smaller screens you could change the css on your right sidebar with something similar to this:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    #content {
        margin-right: 0;
    }
    #rightcolumn {
        margin-left: 0;
        float: none;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are right ! I tried this already But the CONTENT width is also reducing. That is when the screen resolution goes below 600px the content area WIDTH should be 100% of the device. If I chance the margin-right: 340px; in CONTENT property then it also resembles in ABOVE 600px

Comment: Right, you'd also have to change the margin on `#content`. I edited my answer to reflect this.

Comment: margin: 0 auto; was added in #content. It works as 100% width of content in below 600px devices. But when the situation is above 600px the RIGHT COLUMN overlaps in CONTENT as the #content remains always AUTO in margin.  Now i will try with margin-left in #Content

Comment: Wowww.. Your answer is excellant..... It worked well.. Thanking you. Mr. Pschueller.   Note: I am not a web designer. I am doing and learning my own. I think I disturbed you... Any way thanks for your RIGHT COACHING. I was struggling for the past one week without answer. You the right man who saved me. Take Care. Bye

Comment: Sir.. Mr.Pschueller...   Whether this is right.... That is when i add a leftcolumn+ content + rightcolumn and if these three need to open one by one in low resolution, shall i code like below

Comment: @user3342647 It is best if you post a new question. Editing/rephrasing the above answer to ask a new question goes against the website rules, since an answer is only meant to be an answer. But to answer your edit, yes... the same idea applies if it is 3 columns or just 2, you need to remove the floats with `float: none;` and make sure there are no extra margins. Your code looks good.